# Anyone know why the Intel q9400 cpu is embedded?

Tags: cpu, specifications

I was just looking through the Intel site and I came across this -

http://ark.intel.com/ProductCollection.aspx?familyID=28398

Anyone know why the 9400 has a tick in the embedded column? I have tried to contact Intel and not had a response.

I have looked around but cannot find any additional reference and it seems to be available from shops just like any other CPU.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Intel product page for Q9400](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/core2quad/index.htm) describes its embedded applications.
(I just clicked through from your link).
What I do not understand is, how come the [`Q9400S`](http://www.insidehw.com/Reviews/CPU/Intel-Core-2-Quad-Q9400S.html) is not marked embedded.
The latter is a lower TDP version of [Q9400](http://www.legitreviews.com/article/939/1/).

---

Update:
I think this [Intel Embedded Design Center](http://edc.intel.com/Step-by-Step/Why-Intel-Architecture) page might have answers to whats special about the embedded tick on a processor.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, and if no one else answers, I will be happy to select this as answer, however I already read the page you linked to and it is the overall page for the Core 2 Quad CPU range and states embedded, however the page I linked to shows that only that one CPU is embedded... I can't say I fully understand the new definition of embedded, it seems like a normal PC :S

Comment: @Wil, Right! I was trying to understand the same thing. Added a couple of other links from my searches. Would be glad to understand the term `(`and to confirm that its not just a glitch on that page `:-)`

Comment: So, it seems they just picked the 9400 at random to tick embedded :S The new link you posted looks interesting. Is the only difference that you get 7 year support, and it is "supported" for embedded? Personally, I have built a few systems using the 9400 and as far as I thought, it was no different to any other Quad CPU and I just did not understand why it has a tick on the embedded column when compared to the other ones. As you said, if anything, for embedded, I would of thought they would use the low voltage version :S Must be the worst energy inefficient embedded system...

Comment: rated up, and will tick soonish... not sure anyone else can answer better, but I would like to leave this open for a little bit in the hope that someone who has worked with embedded systems / understands this will answer.... Just so confused as to when the definition of embedded changed. Can't imagine seeing a 95watt CPU in a handheld any time soon!

Comment: Thanks, forgot about this post... marking as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not all embedded systems are super low power.  They're also not all aimed for handhelds.  There's industrial applications where high-power CPUs are used in embedded apps.  Usually the chip will be "hardened" in some fashion...